# why flex container width becomes smaller when clicking from file manager?

Tags: html, css, web

I was making the "our team " section of a website. I checked my progress via "visual code studio live server".Everything worked properly. After closing vs code, I clicked the HTML file from file explorer and it opened in google chrome. Then the flexbox container became small and also flex items also became small. Why different result shows when I see the webpage from file explorer and when I see from vs code live server extension [image]

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #f79256;
 font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.team {
 height: auto;
 margin: 1% 1%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card-container {
 width: 220px;
 height: 350px;
 background: #f2f5ff;
 border-radius: 6px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #000;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 05px;
 margin: 05px;

}

div.upper-container {
 height: 90px;
 background-color: #00b2ca;
}
.image-container {
 background-color: #f79256;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 padding: 5px;
 transform: translate(70px, 45px);
}
.image-container img {
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.lower-container {
 height: 280px;
 background-color: #1d4e89;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}
.lower-container h3,
.lower-container h4 {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 line-height: 0.6;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
.lower-container h3 {
 padding-top: 20px;
 color: #fbd1a2;
}
.lower-container h4 {
 color: #fbd1a2;
}
.lower-container p {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #00b2ca;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.lower-container .btn {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #fbd1a2;
 color: #1d4e89;
 padding: 05px 20px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 10px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}
.lower-container .btn:hover {
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #00b2ca;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Profile Card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="team">
   <div class="card-container">
    <div class="upper-container">
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="Person/3.jpg" />
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lower-container">
     <div>
      <h3>Alaina Wick</h3>
      <h4>Front-end Developer</h4>
     </div>
     <div>
      <p>
       sodales accumsan ligula. Aenean sed diam tristique, fermentum mi nec, ornare arcu.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">View profile</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="card-container">
    <div class="upper-container">
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="Person/2.jpg" />
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lower-container">
     <div>
      <h3>Alaina Wick</h3>
      <h4>Front-end Developer</h4>
     </div>
     <div>
      <p>
       sodales accumsan ligula. Aenean sed diam tristique, fermentum mi nec, ornare arcu.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">View profile</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="card-container">
    <div class="upper-container">
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="Person/1.jpg" />
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lower-container">
     <div>
      <h3>Alaina Wick</h3>
      <h4>Front-end Developer</h4>
     </div>
     <div>
      <p>
       sodales accumsan ligula. Aenean sed diam tristique, fermentum mi nec, ornare arcu.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">View profile</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="card-container">
    <div class="upper-container">
     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="Person/3.jpg" />
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="lower-container">
     <div>
      <h3>Alaina Wick</h3>
      <h4>Front-end Developer</h4>
     </div>
     <div>
      <p>
       sodales accumsan ligula. Aenean sed diam tristique, fermentum mi nec, ornare arcu.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn">View profile</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **justify-content** for the team. Don't really know about your environment and your preview